# Prevent Submit Button Jquery On unique username

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Trying to check Unique Category Title Using Ajax and Jquery.

**JQuery and ajax stuff**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#category_title').change(function(){
var category_title = $(this).val();
$.ajax ({
url : "ajax_calls.php",
method : "POST",
data :  {category_title :category_title  },
dataType: "text",
success:function(html)
{
$('#availablity').html(html);
}
});
});
</script>
```

**ajax_call.php**

```
<?php
   include 'commands.php';
   if (isset($_POST['category_title'])) {
       $category_title = $_POST['category_title'];
       $obj= new commands();
       $result= $obj->check_category_title($category_title);
       if (empty($result)) {
           echo "<span class='status-available' style='color:green;'> Username Available.</span>";
       } else {
           echo "<span class='status-not-available' style='color:red;'>Category Already Exist</span>";
       }
   }
   ?>
```

**HTML stuff**

```
<form action="" method="post"  id="my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="tags">Category Title</label>
   <input type="text" name="category_title" class="form-control" id="category_title"><span id="availablity"></span>
   <p class="errorMsg"><?php if(isset($errorTitle) && $errorTitle== 1){echo "Field Required" ;} ?> </p>
</div>
</form>
```

**MySQLi stuff**

```
function check_category_title($category_title){
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT category_title FROM `nm_category` WHERE category_title='$category_title'");
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $result;
}
```

I want to prevent user to submit if the category already exist in table else allow user to submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes like below in your php code :

```
if (empty($result)) {
           echo "<span class='status-available' style='color:green;'> Username Available.</span>";
   //show submit button if no data found
   echo "<input type='submit' value='submit'>";
       } else {
           echo "<span class='status-not-available' style='color:red;'>Category Already Exist</span>";
     //disabled button to prevent submit if category exist
      echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' disabled='disabled'>";
       }
```

Comment: great but how can i show msg of availabe and button of submit differently in html

Comment: beacuase both of them return in same html

Comment: change your `<span>` to  `<div id='availablity'></div>`, also after that `input type` you need to show submit button ,so you can change your html accordingly. i.e you can put `submit` under `div` or add `<br>`  i.e : `echo "<br/><div style='add your css'><input type='submit' value='submit'></div>";` as whatever will be there in `echo` will be send back so make your layout in that way.